# How to find what is hogging the dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bug in my application, where it seems that the dispatcher thread is getting too many requests to process requests with Background priority.

It's a complex application, and the bug happens randomly (or rather, we haven't figured what triggers it), so I have not been able to find a clear scapegoat just by reading the code.

So how can I, when the bug has occurred, find out what the dispatcher is doing, and which code is responsible?

Comment: Did you try to add an hook to handle event `Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted`? It won't highlight _what_ is going on but it may help to understand _who_.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't know that there is a scapegoat yet, but by analysing the symptoms, I know that when the bug occurs, a call to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with Background Priority does not execute the action. WPF in itself does not just suddenly behave like this, so it is most likely something in our code.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I would prefer not to go there. The bug manifests completely randomly, and it can take several hours before it appears. It would just spam the log files.

Comment: I don't mean you have to (manually) monitor each request, you may put there some custom performance counter. When you'll see req/second for Background operation dramatically increases then you'll inspect _who_ posted that requests (also a naive home-made solution without perfcounters may work...)

Comment: Hm. Yes, that could work.

Comment: But a code review/inspection is in order too. This should be UI related code, so anything that posts more than ~ 20 actions per second is faulty. Also any action that does too much or might block.